# Unexpected behavior of c++ program on executing two equivalent statements

Tags: c++, vector, operator-precedence, conditional-operator

I was trying to solve [this problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/range-sum-query-2d-immutable/),

while doing so,
it looks like

```cpp
for (int i=row1; i<=row2; i++) {
    if (col1 != 0) sum -= mat[i][col1-1];
    sum += mat[i][col2];
}
```

and

```cpp
for (int i=row1; i<=row2; i++) {
    sum += (mat[i][col2] - (col1 != 0) ? mat[i][col1-1] : 0);
}
```

are equivalent, but executing the later results in following error

```bash
Line 1038: Char 34: runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x618000000080 overflowed to 0x61800000007c (stl_vector.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:34
```

Am I missing something?, Thank You In Advance.

`complete program:`

```cpp
class NumMatrix {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> mat;
    NumMatrix(vector<vector<int>>& matrix) {
        mat = matrix;
        for (int i=0; i<matrix.size(); i++) {
            for (int j=1; j<matrix[0].size(); j++)
                mat[i][j] += mat[i][j-1];
        }
    }
    
    int sumRegion(int row1, int col1, int row2, int col2) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i=row1; i<=row2; i++) {
            if (col1 != 0) sum -= mat[i][col1-1];
            sum += mat[i][col2];
            
            // sum += (mat[i][col2] - (col1 != 0) ? mat[i][col1-1] : 0); // this gives error :
            // Line 1038: Char 34: runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x618000000080 overflowed to 0x61800000007c (stl_vector.h)
            // SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:34
        }
        
        return sum;
    }
};

/**
 * Your NumMatrix object will be instantiated and called as such:
 * NumMatrix* obj = new NumMatrix(matrix);
 * int param_1 = obj->sumRegion(row1,col1,row2,col2);
 */
```

Comment: The ternary operator `?:` has lower precedence than minus `-` so `mat[i][col2] - (col1 != 0) ? mat[i][col1-1] : 0` is testing whether `mat[i][col2] - (col1 != 0)` is zero or not, which is probably not intended.

Comment: op> If the two statements do not have the same behavior, shouldn't you conclude that they are not equivalent?

Comment: It's also worth noting that this does not solve the linked problem.

Comment: Thanks @Matt, for such an easy explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement

```
sum += (mat[i][col2] - (col1 != 0) ? mat[i][col1-1] : 0);
```

is equivalent ti

```
sum += (mat[i][col2] - (col1 != 0) ) ? mat[i][col1-1] : 0;
```

So for example if this expression `(mat[i][col2] - (col1 != 0) )` is not equal to `0` then you will have in fact

```
sum += mat[i][col1-1];
```

even when `col1` is equal to `0`.

It seems you mean

```
sum += mat[i][col2] - ( (col1 != 0) ? mat[i][col1-1] : 0);
```

Pay attention to that this function

```
int sumRegion(int row1, int col1, int row2, int col2) {
```

is unsafe. There is no check whether row1, row2, col1 and col2 are in valid ranges.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, and I didn't put the bound checks because question Constraints assures that  row1, row2, col1 and col2 are in valid ranges.